# AngularJS ngClass - Expression and Values

Tags: angularjs

I need to use both expressions and values in my ngClass:

The expression is : `ngClass="{'ns-show' : notif.isActive, 'ns-hide' : !notif.isActive}"`

The values would be: 'ngClass="[notif.type, notif.effect]"

Here `notif.type` and `notif.effect` contain the name of a class, for instance `ns-growl`.

I tried `ngClass="{'ns-show' : notif.isActive, 'ns-hide' : !notif.isActive}[notif.type, notif.effect]"`, but I get an error:

```
Syntax Error: Token ',' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 50 of the expression
```

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Yes, This is incorrect, you can just think of it as an expression that will fail anyways.. You can use an array completely or use a method that will return the class...

Comment: what are you trying to do with [notif.type, notif.effect]? Could you not just do ngClass="{'ns-show' : notif.isActive, 'ns-hide' : !notif.isActive}

Comment: the `notif.type` contains the name of a class

Comment: its unclear what you're trying to do. Perhaps if you mentioned what you were expecting to happen by adding [...]

Comment: `ng-class="[notif.type, notif.effect, notif.isActive ? 'ns-show' : 'ns-hide']"`

Comment: @Blackhole, beautiful! Post this as an answer, and I'll vote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple binding for the expressions and keep the ng-class for your mapping, this will combine your classes:

```
<div class="{{notif.type}} {{notif.effect}}" ng-class="{'ns-show' : notif.isActive, 'ns-hide' : !notif.isActive}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Because Angular does not have 'ng-show' class, I'm going back to my original answer

```
ng-class="{ng-show:notif.isActive, ng-hide:notif.isActive, notif.effect:ture, notif.type:true}"
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wAwV3oSsxpYavbCTCyeo?p=preview)

---

additional workable solution would be

```
ng-hide="!notif.isActive" ng-class="[ng-show, notif.type, notif.efect]"
```

Comment: Could you explain why your answer is the solution to the question?

Comment: The class `ns-show` is not just a display property. It contains CSS transition.

Comment: functionally, how is ng-show = "notif.isActive" different than ngClass="{'ns-show' : notif.isActive, 'ns-hide' : !notif.isActive}"?

Comment: @ChiRow, as I said, my `ns-show` class is NOT just a display property. It has other CSS properties. `ngShow` is only a display property. So functionally, they are very different.

Comment: @Kousha, I found the difference.  Angular only deploys 'ng-hide' class.  It does not have an 'ng-show' class.  Thanks.